# What are edges called that always appear in cycles together?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, equivalence-relations

Definition. Two edges e1 and e2 of a graph are called ??? if for any given cycle C they are either both in C or both not in C.

What are such edges called?

The definition obviously defines an equivalence class on the set of edges, what are these classes referred to as?

Comment: Your definition isn't very clear. The use of the word "given" suggests that $C$ is fixed in advance, but I don't think that's what you mean. I think you mean that for every cycle $C$, $e_1$ is in C iff $e_2$ is in $C$. I don't know of a name for this concept.

Comment: Is there a problem that motivated this definition?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, thanks, this is what I meant. Your definition is clearer.

Comment: @MishaLavrov:  Consider the  polynomial $K=\sum_{ S} \prod_{e_i \notin S} \tau_i$, (where the sum is over all  spanning trees $S$, and $\tau_i$ are real variables associated to the edges).  When two  edges, say $e_1$ and $e_2$ have the mentioned property, the polynomial depends on $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ only in the combination $\tau_1+\tau_2$. This polynomial arises in particle physics when computing Feynman graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of terminology exactly describing these, but here is a bit more information about how these edges are related.

First, there is one big equivalence class of this relation: the [bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)). These are the edges not on *any* cycles, and so they are all equivalent. In the intended application of computing the polynomial $$K = \sum_{S} \prod_{e_i \notin S} \tau_i$$ over all spanning trees $S$, these stand out especially in that they do not affect the product at all.

For all other cases, we can look at the slightly stronger equivalence relation: $e_1 \sim e_2$ if (1) these edges are part of at least one cycle together, *and* (2) every cycle that contains one edge, also contains the other. This $\sim$ is a refinement of a more well-known definition: if we *only* include condition (1), then the equivalence classes of the edges are exactly the [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(graph_theory)) or [biconnected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) of the graph. So we can look at each block separately to study $\sim$.

(We can also, actually, look at each block separately to study the polynomial $K$. The intersection of a spanning tree of the graph with a block is exactly a spanning tree of the block; conversely, if we take a spanning tree of each block, their union is a spanning tree of the graph. So if we compute similarly-defined polynomials $K_1, K_2, \dots, K_t$ for each block, then $K$ is their product $K_1 K_2 \cdots K_t$.)

Looking at a block means looking at a graph $G$ which is $2$-connected. In this case, if $e_1 \sim e_2$, then $e_1$ is not on any cycles of $G - e_2$, which means it is a bridge; therefore $G - \{e_1, e_2\}$ is not connected. Therefore $e_1 \sim e_2$ if and only if $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is an [edge cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cut) of $G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree with all you say. I think your answer also implies that the contrary of the polynomial property I mentioned is also true. This is because $K_{G-e_i}=\partial_{\tau_i}K_G$, and hence if $K$ only depends on $\tau_1+\tau_2$ then $K_{G-e_1-e_2}=0$. But $K_G=0$ iff $G$ is disconnected. Hence, $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is an edge cut.